# hypothesis testing problem with two rows clarification

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared

I have the following problem where I have to test the hypothesis for difference in proportions in the voters for the Republicans party.

$$ 
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
n & \text{East} & \text{Middle West} & \text{South} & \text{West} \\
\hline
Republicans & 275 & 228 & 202 & 248 \\
Democrats & 225 & 272 & 298 & 252 \\
Total  & 500 & 500 & 500 & 500
\end{array}
$$

I understand that I have to use Chi-Square Test statistic and then see whether it overpasses the significance level,i.e.:

$T=\sum\frac{(Observed_i-Expected_i)^2}{Expected_i}$

I don't really get what is the expected value in this case.
I assume the Observed is $\frac{275}{500}, \frac{228}{500}$, and so on, but what is the expected proportion considering the fact that we have two rows. If the rows was 1 I would just divide n by 4, but in this case I'm not entirely sure what to do.